# Having trouble scaling the font-size to the frame's height/width

Tags: swift, xcode, font-size

I'm using the iPhone 11 as the baseline and I'm trying to get the font-size to scale up when I run it on an iPad, but I cannot get it to work.

I'm doing everything programmatically and I'm also using auto-layout on the views, textfields, labels, and textviews. I tried playing around with adjustsFontSizeToWidth and minimumScaleFactor, numberOfLines but to no avail. I can't get the font size to change when I scale up to the iPad. Here is what it looks like...

I'm still learning and I'm relatively new to programming and Swift, and I tried asking this question before, but I guess I was too vague with my question.

Please let me know if you need me to include some code with this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also do everything programmatically and I'd suggest you to use [UIKitPlus](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/UIKitPlus) library which will solve a lot of your problems

e.g. you could set different font-size for different devices or device types easily

```swift
TextView().font(.helveticaNeueRegular, 16 !! .iPad(24))
```

As you could see in the example above you could set some value as usual, and also you could provide another value for the different type of device trough `!!` operator.

It is really easy and convenient to use.

The whole your view controller may look like

```swift
import UIKitPlus

class MyViewController: ViewController {
    @State var weight = ""
    @State var repetitions = ""
    @State var notes = ""

    override func buildUI() {
        super.buildUI()
        body {
            VStack {
                Text("Bench Press")
                    .color(.black)
                    .font(.articoBold, 32)
                    .edgesToSuperview(top: 16, leading: 16)
                VSpace(32)
                TextField($weight)
                    .placeholder(AttrStr("Total weight").foreground(.lightGray).font(.articoRegular, 14))
                    .leftView(HStack {
                        HSpace(4)
                        Text("Weight (lbs)").color(.black).font(.articoMedium, 14)
                        HSpace(4)
                    })
                    .color(.black)
                    .font(.articoRegular, 14)
                    .keyboard(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                    .returnKeyType(.next)
                    .tag(0)
                    .shouldReturnToNextResponder()
                TextField($repetitions)
                    .placeholder(AttrStr("Number or Reps...").foreground(.lightGray).font(.articoRegular, 14))
                    .leftView(HStack {
                        HSpace(4)
                        Text("Repetitions").color(.black).font(.articoMedium, 14)
                        HSpace(4)
                    })
                    .color(.black)
                    .font(.articoRegular, 14)
                    .keyboard(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                    .returnKeyType(.next)
                    .tag(1)
                    .shouldReturn { $0.resignFirstResponder() }
                VSpace(32)
                HStack {
                    Image(nil).size(40)
                    HSpace(8)
                    Text("Timer").color(.lightGray).font(.articoMedium, 14)
                }
                .alignment(.center)
                VSpace(32)
                TextView($notes)
                    .placeholder("Notes...")
                    .color(.black)
                    .font(.articoRegular, 14)
                VSpace(32)
                Text("Set 1 0 lbs - 0 Reps").color(.black).font(.articoRegular, 14)
                VSpace(16)
                Text("Set 2 0 lbs - 0 Reps").color(.black).font(.articoRegular, 14)
                VSpace(16)
                Text("Set 3 0 lbs - 0 Reps").color(.black).font(.articoRegular, 14)
                VSpace(16)
                Text("Set 4 0 lbs - 0 Reps").color(.black).font(.articoRegular, 14)
                Space()
                HStack {
                    Button("Next Set").onTapGesture {
                        print("next set tapped")
                    }
                    Button("Next Excercise").onTapGesture {
                        print("next excercise tapped")
                    }
                }
                VSpace(32)
            }
            .alignment(.center)
            .edgesToSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```